# Not using Past Perfect in constructing past unreal conditionals

Tags: conditional-constructions

> If I *didn't go* to the show business, I *was going to become* a fireman. (Curb Your Enthusiasm)

It is real life English, seems very incorrect to me, because the guy actually went to show business, so it is *the unreal conditional*. For me it should be "If I **had not gone** to the show business, I **would have been going** to become a fireman."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, sort of.  This is correct:

> One day in high school I remember thinking that if I didn't go into show business I was going to become a fireman.

This is putting this sentence into the past:

> I think that if I don't go into show business I'm going to become a fireman.

So, to make it correct there is a lot of implied context, meaning that it's informal but not incorrect.

Your sentence is awkward.  I don't remember seeing "I would have been going to..." before more than maybe a couple of times in my life.  I would say "If I hadn't gone into show business I would have become a fireman."